# In Ruby Why is the If/Then logic written without the If/Then structure failing?

Tags: ruby, if-statement

Why does the following code fail to produce expected output, for the first two test cases if I don't add the "then" section to the the 'If?' I set the default value of the second variable "False" and I was under the impression that in Ruby a method could take an unspecified number of parameters, and the lack of a parameter when the method is called will roll back to using the default values of that parameters within the method if set.

```
def alphabetize(arr,rev=false)
   arr.sort! 
   if rev == true
       arr.reverse!
   end
end

numbers = [1,9,2,1,10]
```

**Test cases:**

```
print alphabetize(numbers,false)
=begin
input: numbers,false  
output: nil  
expected output: 1,1,2,9,10
=end

print alphabetize(numbers)
=begin
input: numbers  
output: nil  
expected output 1,1,2,9,10
=end

print alphabetize(numbers,true)
=begin
input: numbers,true  
output: 10,9,2,1,1  
expected output: 10,9,2,1,1
=end
```

**This code produced the expected results:**

```
def alphabetize(arr,rev=false)
   if rev == true
       arr.sort!.reverse!
   else
       arr.sort!
   end
end

numbers = [1,9,2,1,10]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are printing the return value of the `alphabetize` method, which is not necessarily the value of the array.

In your first code, you have an `if` **without** a corresponding `else` as the last statement. In Ruby, the return value of an `if` statement without an else is `nil`, when the `if` condition fails.

In your second code, you have an `if` **with** an `else` statement. So the return value of the method, when the `if`condition fails, will be what gets executed inside the `else` block. In this case, `arr.sort!`.

It's worth mentioning the `alphabetize` method modifies the `numbers` array being passed in (indicated by the `!` in the `sort!` and `reverse!` methods). If you printed `numbers`, instead of return value of `alphabhetize`, you would have the expected output as well.

Comment: If that's the the case, how come the last test case worked?

Comment: @brooklynsweb I've added further clarification. Let me know if it makes sense.

Comment: That explanation makes sense, but then I wrote another example and it behaves as I originally expected; what is the difference? *It's unfortunate that the comments field does not have a code formatting option; here's a pastebin: http://pastebin.com/NGYYpqjB. UPDATE: In other words the second test case did not return a 'nil' it returned nothing because there was no action defined if the 'if' failed.

Comment: @brooklynsweb the difference is that, in your second example, you have the `puts/print` inside the method, not outside. In your original question, you were printing the return of the method, which in turn was the result of the `if/else` inside the method.

Comment: I just updated that code and removed the print inside the method and placed the put outside http://pastebin.com/ZJjcqBLW same result

Comment: @brooklynsweb to check what you mean, in your updated example, `test(0)` returns `nil` (which is equivalent of your first code in the original question). `test(1)` returns `"a > 2"`. Does that sound like what you would expect?

Comment: I just ran that code in rubyfiddle.com and did not get a nil for the updated code, but I do see newline break in the output, so I guess that's kind of similar to a nil? *But in other cases this fiddle clearly returned a 'nil.' In any case guys, I get the gist of, thank you for the breakdown.

Answer (score 0):

```html
def alphabetize(arr,rev=false)
   arr.sort! 
   if rev == true
       arr.reverse!
   end
   arr
end
```

Return array at the end when if false it return nil. To make sure the it returns the array value at the end of method.
Tested on rubyfiddle.com
http://rubyfiddle.com/riddles/c36bc/1